# Build an object from an elements data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given an element like:

```
<div data-answer="42" data-question="?"></div>
```

jQuery `data()` will return the object you expect:

```
{answer: 42, question: "?"}
```

However, jQuery plugins also get added to the internal cache for the element, and will be included with the data:

```
{answer: 42, question: "?", somePlugin: Plugin}
```

I would like to create an object out of the data attributes that are present on the element only, excluding anything added to the jQuery cache.  Is there a simple way, or do I have to loop through the attributes of the element, filter out the non-data-* attributes and construct the object "by hand"?

As noted in Oriol's answer, `elem.dataset` does what I'm asking for, however it is only supported by IE 11--my situation requires the solution work for IE 8+

Comment: In modern browsers... `elem.dataset`

Comment: @cookiemonster & @Oriol `element.dataset` is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for, unfortunately IE < 11 support is required.

Comment: It can be shimmed in IE9/10, and sort of shimmed in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be easy enough to loop through the object, and filter out keys where the element does not have the corresponding attribute.

Alternatively, [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) may be of use:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('yourElementIDhere');
// or any other way of getting the element, doesn't matter
var attrs = elem.attributes;
var data = {};
var attr;
for( var i=0, l=attrs.length; i<l; i++) {
    attr = attrs[i];
    if( attr.name.substr(0,5) == "data-") {
        data[attr.name] = attr.value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, vanilla js it is.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the vanilla-js way:

```
element.dataset;
```

Also see the [`dataset` MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset).

Comment: Pft, shame on me for not knowing about that... disappointing browser support though.